# Make strings uniform -- "AB-CD" === "CD-AB"

Tags: r, string, dataframe, stringr, cran

Sample `dput()` below:

```
structure(list(group = c(34676739L, 45938970L, 22731473L, 40083768L, 
22527333L, 51629537L, 26299463L, 27420157L, 24898717L, 43569190L, 
34573189L, 44503577L, 25471327L, 44630117L, 19048782L, 39710425L, 
33535680L, 54358561L, 27363448L, 39386432L, 44150096L, 24614702L, 
36219027L, 39609036L, 10803983L, 54770896L, 27574728L, 40912817L, 
24679610L, 40261463L), partners = c("US-GB", "US-JP", "US-JP", 
"US-GB", "GB-US", "US-GB", "GB-US", "US-GB", "US-GB", "US-JP", 
"US-GB", "US-GB", "US-GB", "GB-US", "JP-US", "US-JP", "JP-US", 
"JP-US", "US-GB", "US-GB", "US-JP", "US-GB", "GB-US", "GB-US", 
"US-GB", "US-GB", "US-JP", "JP-US", "US-GB", "US-GB")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001fc21f23b00>)
```

**What I want to do**: I want to create a new variable, say `partners_final`, that normalizes the entries in `partners`. You'll see that `partners` has entries `US-GB, GB-US, US-JP, JP-US`. These simply represent relationships between business partners, and so technically, `US-JP == JP-US` and `US-GB == GB-US`.

However, these entries are (obviously) not equivalent in R, which makes it tough when doing empirics. So what I want to do is make a new variable `partners_final` that gives a uniform business partner-pair regardless of the order of the two partners.

**NOTE** that in my actual data set, there are many, many partners. I need to do something that applies to the entire data set, e.g., `partners_final` must reflect that `AB-CD === CD-AB` for all pairs `AB, CD`. Is there any way I can do this in R (preferably avoiding `pivot` as there are some country pairs that don't show up in the data that might later need to be accounted for)?

Comment: Just split each on the dash, sort the two values, and paste them back together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some logic for ordering I assume. In this case, I will assume an alphabetical ordering of the normalized pairs. You could split, sort and re-join.

```
library(stringr)
d <- structure(list(
  group = c(
    34676739L, 45938970L, 22731473L, 40083768L,
    22527333L, 51629537L, 26299463L, 27420157L, 24898717L, 43569190L,
    34573189L, 44503577L, 25471327L, 44630117L, 19048782L, 39710425L,
    33535680L, 54358561L, 27363448L, 39386432L, 44150096L, 24614702L,
    36219027L, 39609036L, 10803983L, 54770896L, 27574728L, 40912817L,
    24679610L, 40261463L
  ),
  partners = c(
    "US-GB", "US-JP", "US-JP",
    "US-GB", "GB-US", "US-GB", "GB-US", "US-GB", "US-GB", "US-JP",
    "US-GB", "US-GB", "US-GB", "GB-US", "JP-US", "US-JP", "JP-US",
    "JP-US", "US-GB", "US-GB", "US-JP", "US-GB", "GB-US", "GB-US",
    "US-GB", "US-GB", "US-JP", "JP-US", "US-GB", "US-GB"
  )
),
row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
)


d$cleaned <- lapply(str_split(d$partners, "-"), 
                    function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "-" ))
```

Comment: oof... and now I see someone commented the same thing whilst I was writing this

Comment: It's still the correct answer - I had exactly the same idea haha